# P is a projective module. Prove that there exists $F$ free such that $P \oplus F \cong F$

Tags: homological-algebra, projective-module, free-modules

P is a projective module. Prove that there exists $F$ free such that $P \oplus F \cong F$

I am trying the following idea:

Since $P$ is projective it is the direct summand of a free module $F_0 = P\oplus T$. Then take $F = \underset{i \in \mathbb{N}}{\oplus}F_0$. With this we have:

$$ P \oplus F = P \oplus(\underset{i \in \mathbb{N}}{\oplus}F_0) = P \underset{i \in \mathbb{N}} \oplus (P\oplus T ) =$$
$$ = P \underset{i \in \mathbb{N}}\oplus (T\oplus P) = \underset{i \in \mathbb{N}} \oplus (P\oplus T ) = \underset{i \in \mathbb{N}}{\oplus}F_0 =F$$

First is this completely correct?

Second is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is it $\otimes$ or $\oplus$ in the question?

Comment: You are so right. It is the direct sum.

Comment: Then your proof is essentially correct (apart from some slips in symbols).

Answer (score 7):

The idea is good, but you're misusing the symbols.

Take $T$ such that $P\oplus T$ is free. Take $F=\bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb{N}}(P\oplus T)$. Then $F$ is free as well and
$$
P\oplus F=
P\oplus\bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb{N}}(P\oplus T)\cong
P\oplus\bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb{N}}(T\oplus P)\cong
\bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb{N}}(P\oplus T)=F
$$
with obviously defined isomorphisms.

Comment: What is the reason that you interchanged $T$ and $P$ inside of the brackets in your chain of isomorphisms?

Comment: @gen Just to keep with how the OP started out. If you instead start with $T\oplus P$, there’s no need to swap.

Comment: I see. Let me rephrase my question: why do you need the middle term in that chain of isomorphisms?

Comment: @gen Do you mean the third term? Just to illustrate what's going on and to suggest the isomorphism to employ.

Answer (score 1):

This is the "Eilenberg--Mazur swindle" of homological algebra. It was used by Bass to prove that "big" projective modules are free in [this](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1255637479) very readable paper. In there, you can also find a proof of what you want.